# Spring Boot properties that depend on profile-specific properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties, spring-boot-configuration

I have a Spring Boot application which should connect to different servers in dev and prod, with many services running on those servers. To this point, I have created the configuration like this:

application.properties:

```
server.url.srv1=${server.url.base}/srv1
server.url.srv2=${server.url.base}/srv2
server.url.srv3=${server.url.base}/srv3
```

application-dev.properties:

```
server.url.base=http://192.168.86.17
```

application-prod.properties:

```
server.url.base=https://10.11.12.3
```

Yet when I initialize a bean argument with `@Value("${server.url.srv1}")`, I get a string of "${server.url.base}/srv1" and not "http://192.168.86.17/srv1" or "https://10.11.12.3/srv1" as expected.

Is this doable at all? It should be if the "${}" references are only resolved once all the config files are loaded, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I have searched for an answer on both the [Spring site](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config), on Google (which pointed me to an otherwise useful [Baeldung site](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)), and here, but found nothing relevant to my particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders in the application.properties should work. Please refer sample project I have added with your use case and it work as expected: https://github.com/itsprav/spring-profile-properties-using-placeholder

Comment: I played for a bit with your project and you're right, in your project this works. I'll need to check again if I'm not doing something stupid in mine.

Comment: ...and of course it turns out I am (doing something stupid, that is). I defined a property for dev and prod profiles but not for test, so test profile was failing. And that was the profile I was testing. Stupid me...

Answer (score 0):

When you run your application you must have to set the specific spring-profile to be set in order to get the specific properties defined previously.

There is many ways to set these profiles.

[Setting Profiles in different ways (JVM, Programmatically, Environment Variable...)](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#set-profiles)

Comment: My question is not how to select a profile. My question is, how to configure a property in main application.properties file based on one defined in a profile-specific one.